# convert nested object to one level up object in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

given json : -

```
{
    "_id": "5c1c4b2defb4ab11f801f30d",
    "name": "Ray15",
    "email": "ray15@gmail.com",
    "deviceToken": "dgtssgeegwes",
    "deviceType": "IOS",
    "tokens": [
        {
            "token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI1YzFjNGIyZGVmYjRhYjExZjgwMWYzMGQiLCJhY2Nlc3MiOiJhdXRoIiwiaWF0IjoxNTQ1MzU4MTI2fQ.YdK0MjOm7Lff22uTFITQdic0gKdMZRpsmRee-yejDpQ"
        }
    ]
}
```

desired json: -

```
{
  "_id": "5c1c4b2defb4ab11f801f30d",
  "name": "Ray15",
  "email": "ray15@gmail.com",
  "deviceToken": "dgtssgeegwes",
  "deviceType": "IOS",
  "token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI1YzFjNGIyZGVmYjRhYjExZjgwMWYzMGQiLCJhY2Nlc3MiOiJhdXRoIiwiaWF0IjoxNTQ1MzU4MTI2fQ.YdK0MjOm7Lff22uTFITQdic0gKdMZRpsmRee-yejDpQ"
}
```

I want to convert JSON with the help of lodash library of npm in javascript or suggest any other library,

it might be a silly question, Please explain it properly, I am a newbie in javascript and try to learn node.js. comment me if you need more explanation.

Thanks for help

Comment: How would you anticipate handling the situation where the `tokens` property has more than one `token` value?

Comment: Or how about the situation where the `tokens` property has zero values?

Comment: It is just a reference, actually i am learning how to converting the array and objects in javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of ways to solve this problem and no one "right" way. However, you may want to consider creating a new object, rather than mutating the original object. Objects are always passed by reference in JavaScript and it's easy to accidentally modify an object inside a function, not realizing that you just changed that object everywhere else it's referenced as well.

Since you mentioned it, here is a way to solve this with Lodash.

```js
const obj = {
    "_id": "5c1c4b2defb4ab11f801f30d",
    "name": "Ray15",
    "email": "ray15@gmail.com",
    "deviceToken": "dgtssgeegwes",
    "deviceType": "IOS",
    "tokens": [
        {
            "token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI1YzFjNGIyZGVmYjRhYjExZjgwMWYzMGQiLCJhY2Nlc3MiOiJhdXRoIiwiaWF0IjoxNTQ1MzU4MTI2fQ.YdK0MjOm7Lff22uTFITQdic0gKdMZRpsmRee-yejDpQ"
        }
    ]
};

// create a new object without the tokens property
const newObj = _.omit(obj, 'tokens');

// get the first token object from the tokens array
const tokenObj = _.head(obj.tokens);

// get the token string from the token object, defaulting to empty string if not found
newObj.token = _.get(tokenObj, 'token', '');

console.log(newObj);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Lodash is a great library and used by many projects. It can be especially helpful for new developers. For example, `_.head(arr)` will return `undefined` if `arr` is undefined. However, `arr[0]` would crash in the same scenario.

Here's one way to solve it without a library.

```js
const obj = {
    "_id": "5c1c4b2defb4ab11f801f30d",
    "name": "Ray15",
    "email": "ray15@gmail.com",
    "deviceToken": "dgtssgeegwes",
    "deviceType": "IOS",
    "tokens": [
        {
            "token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI1YzFjNGIyZGVmYjRhYjExZjgwMWYzMGQiLCJhY2Nlc3MiOiJhdXRoIiwiaWF0IjoxNTQ1MzU4MTI2fQ.YdK0MjOm7Lff22uTFITQdic0gKdMZRpsmRee-yejDpQ"
        }
    ]
};

// create a copy of the original object.
// note that Object.assign will make a shallow copy of our object,
// so newObj.tokens will be a pointer to obj.tokens.
// in this instance, we don't care, as we are going to remove newObj.tokens anyway.
const newObj = Object.assign({}, obj);

// throw away the tokens property.
// OK to mutate newObj as we know it is not used anywhere else.
delete newObj.tokens;

// get the first token object from the tokens array.
// the (expectedArray || []) pattern ensures we have an array if obj.tokens is null or undefined.
const tokenObj = (obj.tokens || [])[0];

// get the token string from the token object.
// again, using the (expectedObject || {}) pattern in case tokenObj is null or undefined.
const token = (tokenObj || {}).token;

// create a new property called "token" on our newObj object.
// set it to our token value or an empty string if token is null or undefined.
newObj.token = token || '';

// of course, if you know the tokens array will always have a valid token object,
// you can simply use newObj.token = obj.tokens[0].token.

console.log(newObj);
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need a library, you can just assign the property and delete the other.

However `tokens` is an array, which suggest there might be more than one. This will only take the first one (`obj.tokens[0].token`). Since objects can't have duplicate keys, you will only be able to have one token with your desired format (if that matters).

```js
let obj = {
    "_id": "5c1c4b2defb4ab11f801f30d",
    "name": "Ray15",
    "email": "ray15@gmail.com",
    "deviceToken": "dgtssgeegwes",
    "deviceType": "IOS",
    "tokens": [
        {
            "token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI1YzFjNGIyZGVmYjRhYjExZjgwMWYzMGQiLCJhY2Nlc3MiOiJhdXRoIiwiaWF0IjoxNTQ1MzU4MTI2fQ.YdK0MjOm7Lff22uTFITQdic0gKdMZRpsmRee-yejDpQ"
        }
    ]
}

obj.token = obj.tokens[0].token 
delete obj.tokens
console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using destructuring assignment with "empty" representations of your types works nicely. `transform` produces a reliable output when `tokens` contains zero, one, or many `{ token: ... }` values.

```js
const emptyUser =
  { _id: 0, name: "", tokens: [] }
  
const emptyToken =
  { token: "" }

const toSingleTokenUser =
  ({ tokens: [ { token } = emptyToken ], ...u } = emptyUser) =>
    ({ ...u, token })

console .log
  ( toSingleTokenUser ({ _id: 1, name: "a", tokens: [ { token: "t" } ] })
    // { _id: 1, name: "a", token: "t" }
    
  , toSingleTokenUser ({ _id: 1, name: "a", tokens: [] })
    // { _id: 1, name: "a", token: "" }
    
  , toSingleTokenUser ({ _id: 1, name: "a", tokens: [ { token: "t1" }, { token: "t2" } ] })
    // { _id: 1, name: "a", token: "t1" }

  , toSingleTokenUser ({ foo: "bar", tokens: [ { token: "t" } ] })
    // { foo: "bar", token: "t" }
  )
```